# Matlab - filtering labeled matrix according to regionprops

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have labeled an image (using `bwlabel`) and, after that, I've used `regionprops` to get the eccentricities of the labeled objects. What I want to do now is to filter every labeled object whose eccentricity is under 0.5.

So far, I've been able to use `find` to get the number of those regions that match the criteria, but I don't know how to use them to filter the original labeled image.

For instance:

```
labeledImage = bwlabel(originalImage);
properties = regionprops(labeledImage, 'eccentricity');
eccentricities = cat(1, properties.Eccentricity);

regions = find(eccentricities > 0.5);
% now what?
```

I've tried to do it using `for` loops, but it's slow as hell and I'm sure there must be a hidden matlab function to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you are still trying to solve this, consider the following example:

```
BW = imread('text.png');

CC = bwconncomp(BW);
L = labelmatrix(CC);

props = regionprops(CC, 'eccentricity');
idx = ( [props.Eccentricity] > 0.6);

BW2 = ismember(L,find(idx));    %# filter components with Eccentricity>0.6
BW3 = ismember(L,find(~idx));   %# filter components with Eccentricity<0.6

subplot(131), imshow(BW)
subplot(132), imshow(BW2)
subplot(133), imshow(BW3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like the function `ismember` did the trick, but I'm sure you guys know better ways of doing it.